# redux reselect fat arrow function argument with assigning

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reselect

i am new to redux and es6. I m little confused with below fat arrow function. I know fat arrow function. But What this **( record = EMPTY_OBJECT )** does? are we assigning default value(Empty Object) if no arguments found ?

```
       const EMPTY_OBJECT = {};                               
       this.getSelectedUser = Reselect.createSelector( 
          this.getUserRecords, 
          (record = EMPTY_OBJECT) => record.selectedUser || EMPTY_OBJECT 
       );
```

Comment: default function parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exaclty what is happenning, by **EMPTY_OBJECT** they literally mean empty object for a default value, otherwise if you do not provide a default one, an error will occur on the component that depends on this value. The default value can be anything, not just an object, but most of the times is either object or array.